# Unit Testing Nested HTTP Calls with Angular 7

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a service method in Angular 7 to get photos which are stored in the cloud by first requesting the google uri from the backend, and then querying the returned uri for the photo blob. Since there can be many nested photos, this process maps the blobs onto the previous media

```
public getPhotos(media: Media[]): Observable<any[]> {
  return forkJoin(media.map((media: Media) => {

    return this.http.get<any>(`http://www.test.net/media/${media.mediaId}?mediaType=${media.mediaType}`).pipe(
      switchMap(data => {

        return this.http.get<any[]>(data.signedUrl, {
          responseType: 'blob'
        })
      })
    )
  }))
}
```

I'm trying to test this, but my tests give false positives and then error out with: `Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined at HttpXsrfInterceptor.intercept`.

Here are my tests:

```
it('should get photos', () => {
  let api: string = 'http://www.test.net'
  let mockMedia: Media = mock(Media) // ts-mockito
  mockMedia.mediaId = '123'
  mockMedia.mediaType = 'jpg'

  let mockUri: string = 'http://google.photo.com'

  imageService.getPhotos([mockMedia], '456', api).subscribe((uri: any) => {
    expect(uri).toEqual(mockUri)
  })

  const req1 = testControl.expectOne(`${api}/media/123?mediaType=jpg`)
  expect(req1.request.method).toEqual('GET')

  // const req2 = testControl.expectOne(`${mockUri}`)
  // expect(req2.request.method).toEqual('GET')

  req1.flush(mockUri)
})
```

How can I test the nested http call and flush fake data into it? Am I doing this test wrong due to the `forkJoin`?

I tried nesting a flushed request inside the first subscribe like so, but that also didn't work (false positive, same error as above):

```
imageService.getPhotos([mockMedia], '456', api).subscribe((uri: any) => {
    expect(uri).toEqual(mockUri)

    const req2 = testControl.expectOne(`${mockUri}`)
    expect(req2.request.method).toEqual('GET')

    req2.flush(['image1'])
  })
```